# How to get one field from model in django

Tags: python, django, model, field

I have such a model, in my django application. I want to draw only one field of this model and put them in the view. My solution below does not work:

```
obj = Text.objects.get(subsID)
```

**My model**

```
result = braintree.Subscription.create({
        "payment_method_token": payment_method_token,
        "plan_id": "67mm"
        })

subscription_id = result.subscription.id

class Text(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_from = models.DateTimeField('date from', blank=True, null=True)
    date_to = models.DateTimeField('date to', blank=True, null=True)
    subsID = models.CharField(default=subscription_id, max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**My view**

```
def get_history(request):
    subscription_id = Text.objects.filter(subsID)
    history = braintree.Subscription.find(subscription_id)
    return render(request, "sheet/history.html", {"history": history})
```

Comment: Show your full view, please.

Comment: "`Text.objects.filter(subsID)`" what is `subsID`?

Comment: @itzmeontv please check my update - this is subsciption from Braintree

Answer (score 29):

Generally, When `filter` or `get`, you have to put query inside it, like

```
subscription_id = Text.objects.filter(fieldname="searchterm")
```

This will return a `queryset`.So to view this

```
subscription_id.values() #returns a list of objects(dicts)
```

If you want to get only `subsID`

```
subscription_id.values("subsID")
```

This also return you list which contains

```
[{"subsID":"value"}, {"subsID":"value"} ....]
```

If you want to get `only` values

```
subscription_id.values_list("subsID", flat=True)
```

This will return like

```
["value", "value", ....]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to equal subsID to the value you want to find.

```
subscription_id = Text.objects.filter(subsID=<your subscrition id variable>)
```

pay attention this will return a list []

```
subscription_id = Text.objects.get(subsID=<your subscrition id variable>)
```

This will return an object

Comment: question is about restricting fields

Answer (score 0):

[Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/)

You can't use the model in the view, you need to use the ModelForm or Form.
Once you use that one, you can specify which field is active or not or simply setting the attribute in the ModelForm,

```
exclude=['paramiter_name']
```

and it's done.

Good luck.

Comment: Anyway my suggestion use ModelForm Are much better to manage.